# Problemas al enviar información de un form a otro

Tags: c#, visual

Mi problema es el siguiente, tengo dos forms, A Y B. El form A contiene un botón que abre el formB. El form B tiene textBox que lleno con datos y también contiene otro botón que genera un evento que toma esos datos y los envía al form1, muestra el form1 y después cierra el formB
Pero cuando sucede eso resulta que nuevamente se abre el formA con los cambios, pero queda abierto otro formA sin los cambios (Por ejemplo, se muestran dos FormA pero uno vacío y el otro con la info indicada en formB), ¿Cómo puedo evitar que se genere este error?
Mi código es el siguiente

```
 private void botonForm1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 GS = new Form2();
            GS.Show();
        }
...
private void botonForm2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form1 f = new Form1();
            f.LX.Visible = true;
            f.LY.Visible = true;
            f.LXValor.Text = TBX.Text;
            f.LYValor.Text = TBY.Text;
            this.Hide();
            f.Show();
        }
```

Mi versión de .NET Framework es 4.8

Comment: Lo que sucede es que cuando presionas el boton del form2, estas creando un nuevo form1, por eso es que tienes un form1 (original) y uno nuevo pero vacio

Comment: Saludos, el form vacío es el original y el nuevo es el que contiene los cambios. Acabo de aplicar Application.OpenForms pero solo me muestra el vacío

Answer (score 0):

Mira es como comenta @Heyner Martinez cuando presionas el botón del form2 generas un nuevo form1 sin cerrar el anterior, y si cierras el form1 cerraras toda la aplicación ya que es el Form padre.

Puedes usar un `this.hide();` en el Form1 para ocultarlo y así llamar al Form2 y continuar con tu programa pero la verdad yo no recomiendo que uses `this.hide();` ya que solo ocultas tu form y a lo largo del uso de tu aplicación tendrás muchas ventanas abiertas y eso consumirá los recursos del equipo.

Para eso te recomiendo que crees una clase que comunique tus 2 Forms ejemplo

Creas la clase para comunicar tus 2 forms y predefines tus métodos con los valores que recibirá del form2. en este caso mi clase se llama `ComunicarForm`

```
   public interface ComunicarForm
{
     void MonstrarInfo(string valor1,string valor2);
   
}
```

Luego en tu form1 ya haces bien tu método con toda la funcionalidad y en el boton llamas tu form2. Uso `ShowDialog();` para que tenga que atender forzadamente al form2 y no pueda ir al Form1 sin picar el boton de continuar o cerrar la ventana.

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form, ComunicarForm
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void MostrarInfo(string valor1,string valor2)
    {
        label1.Text = valor1;
        label2.Text = valor2;
    }
  
    private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Form2 form2 = new Form2();
        form2.Mostrar = this;
        form2.ShowDialog();
      
    }

}
```

Y ya en tu form2 solo tienes que declarar un objeto de tipo `ComunicarForm` con get and set y en tu botón solo mandas a llamar el método `MostrarInfo()` enviándole por parámetros el valor de tus textbox.  Usa la funcion `dispose();` para liberar los recursos del form2

```
  public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
 


    public ComunicarForm Mostrar { get; set; }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Mostrar.MostrarInfo(textBox1.Text,textBox2.Text);
        this.Dispose();

    }
}
```